# Comment odyssée a pris la signification de voyage/aventure ?

Tags: étymologie, histoire, latin, grec

Odyssée est le nom grec et [Ulysse](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/46733/why-is-odysseus-called-ulysse-in-french) le nom latin du héros.
Il m'apparait alors bien étrange qu'en français (et d'autres langues) odyssée veuille dire voyage ou aventure, et que le titre de l'œuvre soit "L'odyssée d'Ulysse".
Ça serait comme dire "le napoléon de Napoléon" (l'empire de l'empereur).

Comment le nom d'odyssée a-t-il pu prendre un nouveau sens (voyage) tout en étant usité exclusivement avec son ancien sens (nom de personnage) ?

Comment: Confusion between Odysseus (a person/character) and odyssee (his voyage)? Sorry for the English.

Comment: @Drew yes I'm confused as to how 2 words of same origin can have different meanings while still used together.

Answer (score 4):

Une retranscription en français d'un des noms grecs d'Ulysse pourrait être Odyssée mais ce nom serait une francisation d'Odysseus (Ὀδυσσεύς) comme Morphée est la francisation de Morpheus.

Le nom commun odyssée est lui la retranscription en français du titre de l'œuvre d'Homère en latin, Odyssea, nom féminin qui lui-même vient du grec *[Ὀδύσσεια](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E1%BD%88%CE%B4%CF%8D%CF%83%CF%83%CE%B5%CE%B9%CE%B1)* (Odusseia). La présence d'un article en français indique bien qu'il ne s'agit pas du personnage mais du récit de ses aventures, comme le mot grec le signifiait aussi.

Si on garde l'analogie avec Napoléon présente dans la question, un ouvrage racontant son épopée aurait pu s'appeler *la napoléonienne*.

Le titre de l'œuvre a toujours été **L'Odyssée** tout court, **L'Odyssée d'Ulysse** est effectivement pléonastique mais n'est pas son nom traditionnel. On le trouve dans quelques éditions à l'attention de la jeunesse.

Comment: D'après l'autre question que j'ai lié et la page wikipedia de ulysse, ulysse et odyssée correspondent à la même chose : le héro roi d'ithaque. Si je comprends ta réponse tu dis que l'origine grec d'odyssée signifiait déjà récit/aventure, pourtant la page que tu lies indique que c'est un nom propre. Si les deux mots ont la même origine comment l'un est devenu commun tout en restant lié à l'autre resté propre ??

Comment: Nom propre ou pas, ce n'était pas le nom du personnage central de l'histoire mais le nom de l'œuvre contant son épopée. Le féminin ne laisse pas de doute sur la différence entre les deux. Que de nom propre en grec, il soit devenu commun en français et d'autres langues est assez logique puisque ce mot a un sens générique aujourd'hui. L'Odyssée reste cependant un nom propre en français quand c'est de l'œuvre qu'il s'agit.

Comment: Je ne vois pas ce qui indique que c'était le nom de l'œuvre. Je vois bien un changement de genre, passage du masculin au féminin. Mais admettons, quel était alors le nom du personnage ??

Comment: C'est dans ma réponse, le personnage est nommé Oddysseus ainsi que de nombreuses variantes, mais il n'a jamais eu de nom féminin.

Comment: Donc le fautif serait l'auteur lui même en donnant quasiment le même nom à l'œuvre et au personnage principal ? Existe t il des exemples similaires dans la littérature ?

Comment: Il n'y a pas de faute. Le nom de l'œuvre est dérivé du nom du héros. *Bambi*, *Harry Potter* ou *Madame Bovary* sont bien éponymes aussi. Comme exemple de nom dérivé, mais hors littérature, on peut mettre en parallèle *Amérique* (féminin) et *Amerigo Vespucci* (masculin).

Comment: On pourrait aussi évoquer les *papinades de Jean-Pierre Papin* ;-)